# SQL query to delete data from 2 tables

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I am currently trying to delete data from a table (`tbl_siphon_req_info`) with conditions from another table (`tbl_siphon_PO`). I am using the following SQL query to do it, but it's still not working:

```
DoCmd.RunSQL " DELETE tbl_siphon_req_info.* FROM tbl_siphon_req_info a, tbl_siphon_PO b WHERE Concat(a.ross_PO_nbr, a.ross_sku12) = Concat(b.PO_ID, Sbstr(bitem_id,1,12))"
```

How do I correct and complete my query?

Comment: Please table your question with the database you are using.

Comment: access db//     tmpquery.Sql = Sql
    tmpquery.ODBCTimeout = 180

    Set tmpquery = Nothing

    strSQL = "INSERT INTO tbl_Siphon_po "
    strSQL = strSQL & "SELECT *FROM tmp "
    CurrentDb.Execute (strSQL)   
    DoCmd.DeleteObject acQuery, "tmp"
End Sub

Comment: 1. This looks like your homework. You should put more effort into it :P,

2. Your title says QUERY to delete data from TWO tables, but your sql statement don't look like it (more like deleted from the tbl_siphon_req_info with conditions from another table).  You may want to rephrase your intention.

Comment: sorry my bad, its like you said, looking from the complete sql is basic  delete  information from one table  with conditions from another table

Answer (score 0):

Not all databases support joins with `delete`, so a typical way to write such as query is:

```
delete from tbl_siphon_req_info ri
    where exists (select 1
                  from tbl_siphon_PO sp
                  where concat(ri.ross_PO_nbr, ri.ross_sku12) = Concat(sp.PO_ID, substr(bitem_id, 1, 12)
                 );
```

Note:  Depending on the database, `substr()` could be spelled `substring()`.  Similarly, `concat()` is available in most databases, infix operators are also available.

Also, a more typical way to write the `where` clause is:

```
                  where ri.ross_PO_nbr = sp.PO_ID and
                        ri.ross_sku12) = substr(bitem_id, 1, 12)
```

The logic is not exactly the same, but this is probably your intention.

Comment: tmpquery.Sql = Sql
    tmpquery.ODBCTimeout = 180

    Set tmpquery = Nothing

    strSQL = "INSERT INTO tbl_Siphon_po "
    strSQL = strSQL & "SELECT *FROM tmp "
    CurrentDb.Execute (strSQL)  
    DoCmd.DeleteObject acQuery, "tmp"

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on the exact database you are using. But you can use:

```
DELETE tbl_siphon_req_info, tbl_siphon_PO
FROM tbl_siphon_req_info AS a
LEFT JOIN tbl_siphon_PO AS b ON concat(a.ross_PO_nbr, a.ross_sku12) = concat(b.PO_ID, sbstr(bitem_id, 1, 12)
```

Comment: here is what i current doing    in vba    
 tmpquery.Sql = Sql
    tmpquery.ODBCTimeout = 180
    Set tmpquery = Nothing

    strSQL = "INSERT INTO tbl_Siphon_po "
    strSQL = strSQL & "SELECT *FROM tmp "
    CurrentDb.Execute (strSQL)DoCmd.DeleteObject acQuery, "tmp"

Comment: The VB script in this case is not relevant. What is important is what DATABASE engine you are using.

Comment: vba and access  is what i using to  create the user interface